# Pandas fill in missing location and count

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like the following with four locations:

```
df
    Date        Location Count
0   2018-11-20  loc 1    22
1   2018-11-20  loc 2    1 
2   2018-11-20  loc 3    5
3   2018-11-20  loc 4    34
4   2018-11-21  loc 1    20
5   2018-11-21  loc 2    2
6   2018-11-22  loc 1    20
7   2018-11-23  loc 3    3
8   2018-11-23  loc 4    21
```

I am looking to fill in the missing locations with a count of 0 so that is looks like:

```
df
    Date        Location Count
0   2018-11-20  loc 1    22
1   2018-11-20  loc 2    1 
2   2018-11-20  loc 3    5
3   2018-11-20  loc 4    34
4   2018-11-21  loc 1    20
5   2018-11-21  loc 2    2
6   2018-11-21  loc 3    0
7   2018-11-21  loc 4    0
8   2018-11-22  loc 1    20
9   2018-11-22  loc 2    0
10  2018-11-22  loc 3    0
11  2018-11-22  loc 4    0
12  2018-11-23  loc 1    0
13  2018-11-23  loc 2    0
14  2018-11-23  loc 3    3
15  2018-11-23  loc 4    21
```

The date is stored a string.  What is the best way to do this?  Should I convert the date first and then apply a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using `pivot` with `stack`

```
df = df.pivot(*df.columns).fillna(0).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Count'})
df
Out[60]: 
          Date Location  Count
0   2018-11-20     loc1   22.0
1   2018-11-20     loc2    1.0
2   2018-11-20     loc3    5.0
3   2018-11-20     loc4   34.0
4   2018-11-21     loc1   20.0
5   2018-11-21     loc2    2.0
6   2018-11-21     loc3    0.0
7   2018-11-21     loc4    0.0
8   2018-11-22     loc1   20.0
9   2018-11-22     loc2    0.0
10  2018-11-22     loc3    0.0
11  2018-11-22     loc4    0.0
12  2018-11-23     loc1    0.0
13  2018-11-23     loc2    0.0
14  2018-11-23     loc3    3.0
15  2018-11-23     loc4   21.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby`, `unstack` and `stack`:

```
(df.groupby(['Date', 'Location'])
   .Count
   .first()
   .unstack(1, fill_value=0)
   .stack(dropna=False)
   .reset_index(name='Count'))

          Date Location  Count
0   2018-11-20    loc 1     22
1   2018-11-20    loc 2      1
2   2018-11-20    loc 3      5
3   2018-11-20    loc 4     34
4   2018-11-21    loc 1     20
5   2018-11-21    loc 2      2
6   2018-11-21    loc 3      0
7   2018-11-21    loc 4      0
8   2018-11-22    loc 1     20
9   2018-11-22    loc 2      0
10  2018-11-22    loc 3      0
11  2018-11-22    loc 4      0
12  2018-11-23    loc 1      0
13  2018-11-23    loc 2      0
14  2018-11-23    loc 3      3
15  2018-11-23    loc 4     21
```

Comment: This one give me the error "TypeError: group() got an unexpected keyword argument 'observed'" @coldspeed

Comment: @sectechguy You're using an older version of pandas. I've removed it, it works fine.

Comment: Ohh I see you removed the observed=True

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) to calculate the Cartesian product:

```
# convert series types for performance
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Location'] = df['Location'].astype('category')

# calculate new index from Cartesian product
cols = ['Date', 'Location']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df[col].unique() for col in cols], names=cols)

# set index, reindex, then reset index
df = df.set_index(cols).reindex(idx, fill_value=0).reset_index()

print(df)

         Date Location  Count
0  2018-11-20     loc1     22
1  2018-11-20     loc2      1
2  2018-11-20     loc3      5
3  2018-11-20     loc4     34
4  2018-11-21     loc1     20
5  2018-11-21     loc2      2
6  2018-11-21     loc3      0
7  2018-11-21     loc4      0
8  2018-11-22     loc1     20
9  2018-11-22     loc2      0
10 2018-11-22     loc3      0
11 2018-11-22     loc4     21
12 2018-11-23     loc1      0
13 2018-11-23     loc2      0
14 2018-11-23     loc3      3
15 2018-11-23     loc4      0
```